# How to wrap an element inside a div?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, jquery-wrap

I would like to wrap the image element inside a `div` element in Polymer 1.0:

```
<template>
      <img src="" alt="Image preview..." id="avatar" class="avatar">
    </template>

<script>
  var $container = document.createElement('div');
  $container.className += " " + 'resize-container';

  var image_target = this.$.avatar;
  var image_target_parent = image_target.parentNode;

  Polymer.dom(image_target_parent).insertBefore($container, image_target);
</script>
```

I don't know how to wrap the `this.$.avatar` inside `$container`.

I'm looking for a jQuery like solution as follows:

```
image_target.wrap('<div class="resize-container"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html), you should use:

```
Polymer.dom($container).appendChild(this.$.avatar);
```

Also your 2nd line, it should be:

```
$container.className = 'resize-container'
```

Otherwise you are setting the class to `.resize-container` which isn't right since you do not use periods in class names.

Comment: @ktiedit The period in the className was a typo. Corrected it. Thanks <br> The image is loaded first. Once its loaded I'm trying to put a container around it for handling crop/resize of the image. The idea is simple i should wrap the elementA inside elementB. where elementB is not in the DOM on page load. I don't want to append/prepend to the elementA.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but does what I suggested originally not do exactly that? I am putting your img (this.$.avatar) into the div you created, that is not in the DOM on page load since it was programmatically created by you...

ie: after your code + my modifications you should see the equivalent of:

    `<template>
      <div class="resize-container">
        <img class="avatar" id="avatar" />
      </div>
    </template>`